# Generate consecutive substring from the string using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I am having a string let say `ABCD` I want to create all the subsets in such a way that they are consecutive like this:

```
`A` ,`AB`, `ABC`, `ABCD`, `B`, `BC`, `BCD`, `C`, `CD`, `D`
```

`AC, AD, BD` etc should not be generated as they are not next to each other.

I tried to write the logic but now I am getting:

[image]

See the highlighted ones. Is it possible to generate consecutive subset using recursion?

**Reason for using recursion is to understand how the recursion works so I am attempting all the questions using recursion only (without loops)**

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:

void print_str(string s){
    for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++)
    {
        cout<<s[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void recur(string st, string ans, int prev, int n, int ind){

    print_str(ans);
    for(int i=prev; i<n;i++){
        recur(st, ans+st[i], i+1, n, ind+1);
    }

    }

};


int main()
{
    Solution sol;
    string st = "ABCD";
    sol.recur(st, "", 0, st.length(),0);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to do it with recursion? 2 nested loops seems sufficient.

Comment: @Jarod42: Yeah I can do with the loops also. But I was trying to learn recursion. So doing every question using recursion only starting from sorting to generating subset.

Comment: Whereas some problems are more natural with recursion, some are not. There are still way to "translate" one to another.

Comment: `print_str` can simply be `std::cout << s << std::endl;` BTW.

Comment: @Jarod42: Ah thanks for pointing this out. I forgot that you can directly print the string but not the arrays(just like python does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With recursion, you might do:

```
void print_seq(std::string_view s)
{
    if (s.size() > 1) print_seq(s.substr(0, s.size() - 1));
    std::cout << s << std::endl;   
}

void print_all(std::string_view s)
{
    print_seq(s);
    if (s.size() > 1) print_all(s.substr(1));
}

int main()
{
    print_all("ABCD");
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/571f15fba18a4cbd)

Comment: Thanks Jarod. I got the logic(your solution). Generate ABCD, BCD, CD, D and then pick one of the string and remove the last element every recursion: `ABCD`-->`ABCD`, `ABC`, `AB`, `A`. So 2 recursion function has been used.

Answer (score 2):

From your rules, it can be said that once you started to append something to `ans`, you mustn't skip characters.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:

    void print_str(const string& s){
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    void recur(const string& st, string ans, int i, int n){
        if (i >= n){
            if (ans!="") print_str(ans); // print non-empty answer
        }else if(ans==""){ // when current answer is empty
            recur(st, ans+st[i], i+1, n); // start appending characters to the answer
            recur(st, ans, i+1, n); // or keep the answer empty
        }else{
            print_str(ans); // print non-empty answer
            recur(st, ans+st[i], i+1, n); // append a character (no choice to skip a character)
        }
    }

};


int main()
{
    Solution sol;
    string st = "ABCD";
    sol.recur(st, "", 0, st.length());
}
```

[Output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zy6EA25WujYCpBgL):

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
B
BC
BCD
C
CD
D
```

Comment: As `st` and `n` are never modified, and `n` is `st.length()`, `n` can be removed.

Comment: Thanks @MikeCAT I still need to process the logic.  I guess the middle 2 recur function is generating `A`, `B`, `C` `D` the last recur function is adding all the next elements `A` --> `A+B`, `A+B+C`....`B`--> `B+C`, `B+C+D`